# Understanding holomorphic tangent space

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I know that for $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$  and $p \in U$ we construct the holomorphic tangent space in the following way.

We take $T_pU$ the real $2n$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$ tangent space.

Now we complexify, i.e. take $T_pU \otimes\mathbb{C}$. We got $2n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ which nicely decomposes into  $T'_pU \oplus T''_pU$.  So we take $T'_pU$ for the holomorphic tangent space.

Usually we take $\frac{\partial }{\partial z^i}, \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z^i}$ for a basis in $T_pU \otimes \mathbb{C}$ so $T'_pU = span(\frac{\partial }{\partial z^i})$  and $T''_pU = span(\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z^i})$. By the construction $\frac{\partial }{\partial z^i}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z^i}$ are linearly independent.

Algebraicly everything is totally fine but we want to think of the tangent space as a space of differentials with the standard basis $\frac{\partial }{\partial z^i}$. But $\frac{\partial }{\partial z^i}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar z^i}$ are not linearly independent as a differentials! I mean, they are determined by their action on functions and they are not independent  over $\mathbb{C}$ at this point.

Comment: So what is your question? Of course, the complexified tangent space is not the same as the tangent space, so of course $\partial_{z_i}$ and $\partial_{\bar{z}_i}$ are linearly dependent as differential operators.

Comment: It means that $\partial_{\bar z}$ are in the tangent space too with differential operator point of view.

Comment: More precisely, there are (natural) isomorphisms $T^{1,0}M\to TM$ and $T^{0,1}M\to M$ sending vectors to certain differential operators; I think, this is what confuses you. I remember that this matter was discussed at MSE many times. It is useful to remember that "are the same" is not the same as "are isomorphic".

Comment: How do you define the right hand side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this confuses you, my suggestion is to use a separate notation, such as 
$\partial_{i}, \bar\partial_k$ (or $\partial_{\bar{k}}$), 
for basis elements of the spaces of sections of $T^{1,0}U$ and $T^{0,1}U$ (regarded as $C^\infty(U)$-modules) and the usual notation 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}, \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_k}$$
for the corresponding differential operators acting on functions $C^\infty (U)$. Then what you have are isomorphisms of vector bundles
$$
\phi^{1,0}: T^{1,0}U \to TU, \phi^{0,1}: T^{0,1}U \to TU,
$$ 
sending 
$$
\partial_{i}\mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i},  \bar\partial_k \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}_k}. 
$$
Then $\partial_{i}$ and $\bar\partial_{i}$ are linearly independent while their images are linearly dependent. After you get comfortable with this thing, you will not need the separate notation.